# Pure CSS drop down with divs on hover

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, block

I'm going for a pretty minimalistic look on my site and I was wondering how I could achieve a look like this:

http://iq.gs/cssdropdown

The top left hand corner in the picture would be transparent or a solid color to match the top navigation bar. What I'm looking to do is to show the six different colored boxes as block elements so when someone hovers over the navigation part, the six boxes drop down and can be used as links. I'm not sure how to do this, as I'm a newbie to CSS.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/SpJ5f/

I didn't bother using the colours/fonts etc you asked for, just the idea behind it